# Check if stdin is empty

Tags: c++, c, stdin

I searched but did not get a relevant answer to this question, i am working on a linux machine, i wanted to check if the standard input stream contains any character, without removing the characters from the stream.

Comment: C++ or C?  Your question is tagged with both.

Comment: I am not sure that your question has a well defined meaning. Imagine the *stdin* being a pipe (from a command which takes ages to spit its first character on its *stdout*). What you could do is call [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) using `STDIN_FILENO` (i.e. 0) as a file descriptor. You then check if *stdin* is readable... (i.e. that [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) won't block).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to try [select()](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman2/select.2.html) function, and wait for having data into the input stream.

**Description:**

> **select()** and pselect() allow a program to monitor multiple file
>   descriptors, waiting until one or more of the file descriptors become
>   "ready" for some class of I/O operation (e.g., input possible). A file
>   descriptor is considered ready if it is possible to perform the
>   corresponding I/O operation (e.g., read(2)) without blocking.

In your case, the file descriptor will be `stdin`

```
void yourFunction(){
    fd_set fds;
    struct timeval timeout;
    int selectRetVal;

    /* Set time limit you want to WAIT for the fdescriptor to have data, 
       or not( you can set it to ZERO if you want) */
    timeout.tv_sec = 0;
    timeout.tv_usec = 1;

    /* Create a descriptor set containing our remote socket
       (the one that connects with the remote troll at the client side).  */
    FD_ZERO(&fds);
    FD_SET(stdin, &fds);

    selectRetVal = select(sizeof(fds)*8, &fds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);

    if (selectRetVal == -1) {
        /* error occurred in select(),  */
        printf("select failed()\n");
    } else if (selectRetVal == 0) {
        printf("Timeout occurred!!! No data to fetch().\n");
        //do some other stuff
    } else {
        /* The descriptor has data, fetch it. */
        if (FD_ISSET(stdin, &fds)) {
            //do whatever you want with the data
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for an instant rply, however, i do not want to wait for the input stream to have the data,
Its just that, if the stream has data, i need to do some processing, if it does not have data, do some other processing. The code should not wait for the input,

Comment: I still think this could help @51k, let me put an example.

Comment: I had to use `0` instead of `stdin` for gcc c++

Answer (score 5):

cacho was on the right path, however `select` is only necessary if you're dealing with more than one file descriptor, and `stdin` is not a POSIX file descriptor (`int`); It's a `FILE *`. You'd want to use `STDIN_FILENO`, if you go that route.

It's not a very clean route to take, either. I'd prefer to use [`poll`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/poll.html). By specifying 0 as the `timeout`, poll will return immediately.

> If none of the defined events have occurred on any selected file
>   descriptor, poll() shall wait at least timeout milliseconds for an
>   event to occur on any of the selected file descriptors. **If the value
>   of timeout is 0, poll() shall return immediately.** If the value of
>   timeout is -1, poll() shall block until a requested event occurs or
>   until the call is interrupted.

```
struct pollfd stdin_poll = { .fd = STDIN_FILENO
                           , .events = POLLIN | POLLRDBAND | POLLRDNORM | POLLPRI };
if (poll(&stdin_poll, 1, 0) == 1) {
    /* Data waiting on stdin. Process it. */
}
/* Do other processing. */
```

Comment: just a heads up, but first time i clicked on the poll link, I was redirected here: http://www3.opengroup.org/  ... secnond time, here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/poll.html  (which seems to be what you intended)